# summation in Access 2007 queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to use access for the first time to get some reports using queries.
I have the following table:

```
Person    Year    CalendarWeek    Hours    ...
  AA       2000         1           53
  AA       2000         2           175
  ...      ...         ...          ...
  AA       2001         1           226
  AA       2001         2           87
  ...      ...         ...          ...
  BB       2000         1           189
  BB       2000         2           65
  ...      ...         ...          ...
```

I need to get the summation of hours in a year for each person. I tried adding a sum row, but since I have the CalendarWeek column, the result is just the hours in that week.
I also need that column for another part of my report so I can't remove it.

Is there any way to get this sum? Or maybe use two queries in one repot?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a group level for Person + Year. But in an Access report, each grouping is only for one field.

You can add the combined field to the source query, e.g.

```
Person_Year: [Person] & " - " & [Year]
```

Then in "Group & Sort" add a Group for `Person_Year`, and in its footer section add a `Sum()` field for `Hours`.

Comment: I believe you could just group first by _Person_ and then by _Year_. In the report, don't display anything for group Person. In group Year, both Person, Year, and `Sum([Hours])` can be displayed.

Comment: @Andre when I add the sum row, what should I choose for each column? sum for hour and Group for Person-Year, and the rest?

Comment: @Andre when I leave it empty, I get error and I think don't need any of other functions.

Comment: You are in the query, right? I meant adding a Group in **Report design**, not in the query.

Comment: @Andre The result I get is the Hours for each week, since I have the CalendarWeek Column. And I need it for other parts of the Report.